# Which rejection vote should be used when reviewing a garbage suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

First thing, lets clear up what I mean by "garbage" edit:

A garbage edit is when completely random text/code has been inserted into a post. This leaves the post making no sense at all. The most common occurrence of these types of edits are the "tests" that we have to endure every now and then in the review queue (which lets be honest, stand out like a sore thumb anyway).

Although, from the test point of view the rejection reason doesn't matter (all that matters is that you reject), what reason should be taken when this kind of edit occurs genuinely?

The two options I am always torn between is "Invalid Edit" and "Radical Change" - and I have started to lean more towards "Radical Change" as, in my opinion, the edit changes the meaning of the post.

Comment: If someone is obviously purposefully editing in random noise, I'd flag vandalism.

Comment: @nijansen: Good point. Perhaps I shouldn't have used "garbage" as my definition. What I meant was understandable words, but doesn't make sense in the context. But if it doesn't make sense, even understandable words are still vandalism I guess...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For posts similar to audit questions where random words or characters are inserted into the post, I think "Vandalism" is the appropriate reason

[image: Suggested Edit Reject Dialog with Vandalism circled]

The reason is the phrase in the 2nd circle "defaces the post in some way".  If the post make no sense at all, then the edit vandalized the post, so it is appropriate.

Comment: +1, forgot about "vandalism".

Comment: @Stijn your answer was valid, I would undelete it.  Invalid edit, specifically, it a good option.  I intentionally didn't include it because it was already in yours.

Comment: I am happy now, I think it is clear that "vandalism" is the option to go for in these situations. Previously I viewed it on it's "spam" merits, and try to limit its use to extreme circumstances (like the spam close vote), but it seems it is more applicable here

Answer (score 5):

"Invalid Edit" when it's random text/garbage.

"Radical Change" when the edit makes sense, but changes the question/answer too much.

Comment: What has always thrown me about invalid edit, is where it says something like "should have been a comment..." (I can't find the definitions at the minute)

Comment: @musefan - "This edit is *incorrect* **or** an *attempt to reply* to **or** *comment *on the existing post."

Comment: @hims056: Ok cool, like I said I can't remember exact wording right now, but that clears things up

Comment: @hims056: Actually, I think random text entry wouldn't match any of those conditions

Comment: @musefan - You can use *incorrect* or *Vandalism* (as [suggested by psubsee2003](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195738/187824))

Comment: Invalid edit is a good option when the edit is somewhat coherent, but still not wrong - typically if someone introduces poor grammar.  Vandalism is better when it isn't even coherent.

Comment: @hims056: Yes, its the "incorrect" bit I am having a problem with. If you say it is OK to use "invalid edit" for this reason, then I think you are viewing "incorrect" as a sort of catch-all term - which would incorrectly make "Invalid Edit" acceptable for all type of rejections. I am think that in this case, "incorrect" means it is a change that makes a correct statement/answer in to an incorrect (wrong) statement/answer

Comment: @musefan like I mentioned in my comment above, semi-coherent attempts to edit - basically looks like the person is making a reasonable attempt to make a solid edit but does a poor attempt due to a language barrier fit better with "Invalid Edit" mostly because it is less offensive.